# texi2dvi: "I couldn't open database file..." (strange behavior with relative paths to .bib file)

Tags: pdftex, texi2dvi

When I use `texi2dvi -p --tidy foo.tex` where `foo.tex` contains `\bibliography{/home/user/.../mybib.bib}`, everything works as expected, `mybib.bib` is found and references inserted in `foo.pdf`. Also, when `mybib.bib` is in the same folder as `foo.tex` and I use `\bibliography{mybib.bib}`. However, if `mybib.bib` is one directory level above `foo.tex` and I use `\bibliography{../mybib.bib}`, `texi2dvi` with the option `--tidy` (as given above) is not working anymore, it gives:

```
I couldn't open database file ../mybib.bib
---line 3 of file foo.aux
 : \bibdata{foo-blx,../mybib
 :                           }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
```

How can I specify relative paths in `\bibliography` so that `texi2dvi` with option `--tidy` does not fail?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have it (fairly simple after all). Since the bib(la)tex-related files are in `foo.t2d/pdf/build`, the relative path in `\bibliography` should be: `../../../../mybib.bib` for `mybib.bib` to be found.